# Is it possible for navigation based application to switch to any other orientation mode?

Tags: iphone

My application is completely navigation based and my query is that navigation based application can switch to any mode i mean orientation to portrait to landscape.

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation controller automatically works in any orientation. Once you rotate your views, the navigation controller rotates with them.

Comment: Note that the view controller must override [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:), but otherwise, yes, it should work fine.